SD-card-reader doesnt work with samsung sdxc-card under windows 10
my sd-card reader doesnt work with a samsung 128 pro-sdxc-card under windows 10 (build: 19045.4412). Other cards, for example sandisk ultra 128gb, works. There are no problems with the same sd-card in the same card-reader under linux (dual boot system). Even my Cannon EOS1100D is able to work with the card, so I think, the windows-driver must be the problem. The actual driver is Gerneric-Multiple Reader USB Device Version 10.0.19041.4355 from 2006-06-21. Is this problem known? Where can I download a driver which works?
thanks for your support
Joerg

Might be easier and safer try another SD card reader on Windows. They're available for US$5 or so, and up -- and I've been using a $5 reader for years with nary an issue.

Despite the simple (physical) appearance of SD cards, the actual electrical and operational interface for reading/writing SD cards is rather complex and has multiple variations. Different voltages and clock speeds can be used. The data interface can be one or four or eight bits wide. And then the card itself can/will report its capabilities (or limitations) to the host. So two SD cards of the same storage capacity might be similar in just one metric.

@sawdust Indeed. That said, and according to the OP's description of the problem, whatever differences are moot. The same card works in Linux ion the same machine, same reader.

@ChanganAuto - One OS driver could access the SD card using a different interface configuration than what another OS does. The specifications for SD cards spans several volumes and thousands of pages. If you haven't seen it, and/or read datasheets of controllers that try to support the various versions of the spec, and reviewed OS drivers that have to use these capabilities, then you surely underestimate the complexity of the interface.

"The actual driver is ... from 2006-06-21" - The spec for Version 3.00 of SDXC is dated 2009. That driver is too old. See https://www.sdcard.org/developers/sd-standard-overview/
